# Creating a group box layout, trying to overlay the titles of the outer border

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

```
Android 4.0.1
```

I can trying to create a group box that will contain some details. But the problem I am having is with the titles that should display over the groupbox's border lines as in the diagram.

[image]

I have used the CoordinatorLayout as I think this would be better for overlaying the border lines and I can anchor on the top start and end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clGroupBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStandardDeliver"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Standard Delivery FREE"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExpressDelivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Express Deliver"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvStandardDeliver" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHomeDeliver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:text="Home Delivery"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/clGroupBox"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:translationZ="20dp"
        android:text="View Details"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/clGroupBox"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, when I run on a device the border lines are always displayed over the text titles. I have tried using translationZ and elevation to bring them forward. But it doesn't work.

This with what I can getting when I run:

[image]

Comment: Set the background on `tvHomeDeliver` and `tvViewDetails` as screen background color .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This Code and you will get a result like below image

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clGroupBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStandardDeliver"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Standard Delivery FREE"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExpressDelivery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Express Deliver"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvStandardDeliver" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHomeDeliver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="Home Delivery"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/clGroupBox"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvViewDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="View Details"
        app:drawableEndCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/clGroupBox"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who have the same problem, you can use this library:

https://github.com/homayoonahmadi/GroupBoxLayout

It doesn't use any white or other color backgrounds for hiding border under the label

Also it supports rtl and ltr directions